# How to know if the UserControl is active other than using IsFocused

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I am working on a WPF project, and I am trying to fire an event every time some userControls get active or inactive.

These userControls have many other controls inside of them.

I tried to achieve this using the userControl events `GotFocus` and `LostFocus`, but these events are not working in the way I need since the userControl loses the focus when I work with controls inside of it.

So, my question is: **Is there a way to mantain a userControl as `Active` while the user works with controls inside of it, and, when the user goes to another userControl this first one gets `Inactive`???**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithinchanged)?

Comment: @LPL, I just tried it, but when the user control is showed the event raises infinitely

Comment: @Dante Are you using a breakpoint? A breakpoint will cause the `UserControl` to lose focus, then Continuing will make it gain focus again, which causes the infinite loop.

Comment: @Rachel No, Im not using any breakpoint, however, the event is being raised infinitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve my problem thank to the comments of @LPL and @Rachel.

I had to use the event `UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged` and it worked perfectly.

At first I had a problem which was that the callback method was being raised infinitely, but the actual problem was that I was showing a `MessageBox` every time the event `IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged` raised, so, this caused that the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` property changed and it created an infinite loop. But thanks to Rachel's advice I could figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but one workarounnd can be on lost focus of the control check if the control that got focus is child of your control if it is write just return if it is not then just write the logic what you want on lost focus of your control. I hope this will help